# Booking conflicting flights with two different airlines

Tags: air-travel

I booked two tickets departing from the same airport:

- One ticket with Airline A, departing at 11:00 to Destination X
- One ticket with Airline B, departing at 12:00 to Destination Y

Normally I would fly to Destination X, but there is a chance I may need to cancel that and go to Destination Y at the last moment. Could these bookings be a problem? (I am of course not expecting a refund or anything, I just need to have both options at the day of travel).

Separate of this, can I do the following: check-in for flight A, leave my luggage, go through security, change my mind, get out, request to get my luggage out and check-in for flight B?

Comment: I'd try not to check in for both. You'll have little chance of your bags following you to the plan b flight as they will get pulled from the hold of the first plane likely after the deadline for the second plane to load up.

Comment: How long does it take to retrieve your bag after it's checked-in and is there a penalty fee for doing that?

Comment: That would vary by aircraft type and availability of staff. Someone has to go hunting around in one of those containers full of bags to try to find yours. Fees: I don't know, but they definitely won't be happy if it caused them to miss the takeoff slot. Could you do hand luggage only?

Comment: No, in fact I have two checked bags with me and hand luggage.

Comment: I don't see how this is practical with checked bags and so little time between the flights. You're likely not going to be able to exit the secure area (depending on the airport and whether immigration is involved, that's anything from "just walk out" to a whole process in and of itself), get your luggage back, go to the other airline's check-in counter, and check-in before the cut-off time.

Comment: How much time would you suggest is appropriate between the flights to make sure everything goes smoothly?

Comment: Is there any chance you can get whoever needs you to go to Y to inform you before 10? That doesn't seem too weird if you're considering a flight leaving at 12, and baggage drops usually close less than 1 hour before the flight these days (of course, you might have to hurry to make it through security in time...)

Comment: I most likely will, but I am still interested in the hypothetical situation where I have just checked in, queued in line for security and suddenly get information that I need to go on my other flight. How much time must I have before the check-in closes so that it would be enough to retrieve my luggage and check it in for the other flight?

Comment: Voting to close as too broad. This is certainly dependent on the airport, type of flights (both domestic? both international? one of each?), etc.

Comment: @Tri-EdgeAI Even beyond the particulars of airport, airline, domestic/international, etc..., nobody can really tell you for sure how long it will take for an airline to retrieve your checked bags if you don't fly. Airports aren't optimized for that case, and it could take quite a while before someone manually takes care of it for you, Or worse, your bag could (in some cases) fly on to Destination X without you.

Comment: Wasn't there a regulation that forces the airline to offload the baggage whenever the passenger has not boarded the plane?